# React Calendly Package infinitely loading

Tags: reactjs, calendly

I am currently using the react-calendly package and everything is working as expected. I am able to pick a date, etc. and post the event to the calendar. The only issue is below the calendar there are 3 gray dots showing the widget is loading. They never go away, the widget appears to be in a constant state of loading. Is there a reason this is happening? Or maybe could offer a separate solution as opposed to the package I am using. Click https://m44fc.csb.app/ to see what I am talking about. Here is the code pen if you would like to test a solution https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-dewdney-m44fc?file=/src/App.js

My code is as follows:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { InlineWidget } from 'react-calendly'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <InlineWidget
        url='https://calendly.com/myURL'
        utm={{
          utmCampaign: 'Spring Sale 2019',
          utmContent: 'Shoe and Shirts',
          utmMedium: 'Ad',
          utmSource: 'Facebook',
          utmTerm: 'Spring'
        }}
      />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

getting the following issue in my chrome dev tools:

Resolve this issue by updating the attributes of the cookie:
Specify SameSite=None and Secure if the cookie is intended to be set in cross-site contexts. Note that only cookies sent over HTTPS may use the Secure attribute.
Specify SameSite=Strict or SameSite=Lax if the cookie should not be set by cross-site requests

Is there something I need to do to resolve these?

Comment: Seems to load fine for me and the loading dots go away. Any errors in the Network panel or Console in Dev Tools?

Comment: is that when you click on the top link? For some reason on my end, it constantly displays those three dots.  I get the following issue in the console: Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its SameSite attribute

Comment: I see these too, but the loading dots go away. I work for Calendly, mind shooting an email to support@calendly.com so that we can help troubleshoot? StackOverflow isn't the best place for user-specific troubleshooting

Comment: when in full screen they never go away, I've been watching them for the past hour.

Comment: I will send the email now

Comment: Please note: your browser must be full-screen

Comment: The issue is with the widget @DmitryPashkevich even in their example the calendly widget is constantly loading.  Giving it a height of 1000px does nothing but cover the dots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the React component is missing an important style property. We'll look into patching it, but in the meantime the workaround is to pass the following styles yourself when you're using the component:

```
<InlineWidget
    url="https://calendly.com/robert-612/complimentary-consultation"
    utm={{
      utmCampaign: "Spring Sale 2019",
      utmContent: "Shoe and Shirts",
      utmMedium: "Ad",
      utmSource: "Facebook",
      utmTerm: "Spring"
    }}
    styles={{
      minWidth: "320px",
      height: '630px', 
      position: 'relative',
    }}
  />
```

The `minWidth` and `height` values are taken from the [component's defaults](https://github.com/tcampb/react-calendly/blob/6d2c8f4bad65f7267f74ad33745c1dea916c0807/src/components/InlineWidget/InlineWidget.tsx#L27-L28), the `position: relative` is what was missing. This should ensure that the widget always covers the loading dots, no matter what the page size is.

Comment: Would it be possible to create a prop that could hide the loading dots?

Comment: In the future we'll change the embed code to automatically hide the loader when the iframe has loaded, that should remove the need for external code to manage it altogether. Don't have a timeline right now though. Would that address your concern?